# user have been remove from domain admins group without any reason

Tags: active-directory

I have a problem that I add a user to Domains Admins Group in Active Directory
and often he been removed from that group without no any idea why.

How I know it?
often when I login to any computer on the domain I saw that I cant restart and shutdown, i Check with "whoami" cmd command and I show that I been removed from Domain Admins without any reason.
I wanna know why is that, and what I can do for cancel/stop it?